# Does the following equality imply probabilistic independence of A and B?

Tags: probability

Suppose that the following equality holds (where $A$ and $B$ are binary propositional variables).

$|P(B|A) - P(B|\neg A)|$ = |$P(\neg A| \neg B) - P(\neg A|B)$|

Does this imply that at least one of the following must be true?

(i) $A$ and $B$ are probabilistically independent

(ii) $P(B|A) = P(\neg A| \neg B)$

If so why, and if not please give a counterexample :)

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are the same event, both sides of your equation are $1$.

(And this even without the absolute-value signs).

If $A$ and $B$ are independent both sides will be *zero*.